# Localhost is no longer working properly

Tags: xampp, localhost

I just built a site using Xampp and it worked great. I just transferred my site (that I used to develop by updating to live server) to localhost, and it isn't working right at all.

The images do not show and the pages are not refreshing properly.

I had to change the CSS images to `/folder/x` instead of just `x`, which I can understand I guess, but why are my HTML images suddenly not working?

One of the pages, the paths are even absolute, but the page just isn't updating even though it's saved in the local folder.

What gives? All I did differently was added a password to root user in MySQL and tried (and failed) at some `mod_rewrite`s, which I removed.

It points the images from `localhost/` instead of `localhost/folder`, even adding `folder/x` doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear where your site was before, and where you moved it to. Did you copy files from one (remote) machine to your own?

Comment: Yes, it was online and all paths were absolute (http://www.site.com/x) and now I've converted everything to relative to try and make it all local (x) where x is the path.

Comment: Your question is still much to general for people to answer. Try to narrow it down as much as possible (e.g. migrating just one HTML page and one image); and give specific details about your environments, the error messages you get etc.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to convert a link or made a mistake.
Remember that /images/x.png means that it's trying to find the folder images from root and not from the current folder your site is located in. Try using ./images/x.png instead.

Perhaps you could post an example from your site?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the Apache [access logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html) and see whether you can find a request for an image with the wrong path.